# How to thicken buttercream without adding more sugar

Tags: frosting

I made some buttercream frosting for brownies using [this recipe](http://wickedgoodkitchen.com/best-ever-baileys-irish-cream-buttercream/).  Because The frosting is going on brownies, it needs to be thicker than what it would be on something like a cupcake.  We typically frost the entire pan of brownies and then cut the brownies into bite sized squares.

But this recipe comes out thinner than I would like for the brownies.  Our usual recipe calls for twice the amount of sugar, but that makes it **really** sweet.  With this recipe, the sweetness is overpowering.

Is there anything else that I can use to thicken the frosting without making it overly sweet?

Comment: Have you tried refrigerating it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a couple of similar recipes in your link there, but you could make it a teensy bit thicker without increasing the sweetness by 1) diminishing slightly the amount of liqueur, or 2) adding a little bit of unsweetened cocoa powder [but of course it will then become brown and chocolatey], or 3) adding a little more cornstarch [since confectioners sugar does contain cornstarch anyway]... or some combination of above.  Go easy at first of course.

Comment: I'll try the cornstarch.  I was tempted to try it, but I'm a little hesitant.

Comment: @MichaelDotKnox The cornstarch (about 3% by weight) in powered sugar is there to stop caking. Adding it with the powdered sugar will not help thicken your frosting, cornstarch must be cooked in a liquid for it to gel.

Comment: @DebbieM. - I would think it should work to thicken just as a powder, since it is making the mix less moist and competing for water - mechanical thickening, not chemical.  I would think an icing made with "powdered sugar, cornstarch removed" would be a touch thinner since it's missing 3% of its weight (small volume difference, but it might make a difference if the goal is to monkey with sweetness).  The boiling lets it thicken a liquid out of proportion to its size, sure, but in a paste or frosting it should thicken roughly equal to other powders.

Comment: @Megha - you are correct, but raw cornstarch has a definite flavor. I can often taste it in glazes and frostings that use powdered sugar. Adding a tablespoon or 2 could really adversely affect the flavor of the frosting.